Can I use waitress with 1 thread, and order the requests by a priority?
I am currently using waittress with 1 thread because I am doing an AI inference API, however i would like to implement a priority queue to order the incomming requests.
Is there any way to make waitress resolve requests in a defined order, or is that not possible?
I've tried multiple thread and an internal queue, however I cant do this because 1 of the model seems to stop working when multiple threads are being executed at the same time
currently using
waitress-serve --threads 1 --host 0.0.0.0 API:app


Sure, you can do that. But, if you won't use thread, just specify threaded to False.
waitress.serve(threaded=False, ...)

Or you can specify the connection limit, by default 100.
waitress.serve(connection_limit=1)

For more information about waitress serve arguments, you can go with this link.
